# can not load require.js main module

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I'm trying to use require.js in my app but it looks like it doesnt see the path of the main.

There is script for loading:

```
<script data-main='public/scripts/main.js' src='public/scripts/require.js'></script>
```

i tried everything /public/scripts/main.js, public/scripts/main and others but im still getting:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at exec (require.js:2410)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (require.js:2421)
```

I think the problem is in the node middleware path, when I'm trying to load it with just index.html and scripts it works, but with whole backend stuff it doesn't :(

There is how I set /public in node:

```
  Server.app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Any one know the solution?

Comment: Also when i load <script src='/public/scripts/main.js'></script> it works

Answer (score -1):

YOu can try again :

```
<script data-main='/public/scripts/main.js' src='/public/scripts/require.js'></script>
```

Comment: I said that i have been trying it a lot of times and still does not work

Comment: Sorry @KacperCzyż.
`app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` It's work with me. Please try again agian.